# Payment fields missing from Authorize.net checkout method

Tags: magento, authorize.net

This is a pretty strange issue. If I enable the Authorize.net payment method, the input fields to enter your CC details is missing from HTML. This is a pretty much out of the box installation with just some theme work having been done, and I didn't touch the opc templates.

If I enable Saved CC payment method, the fields appear correctly.

I did not make any changes to the OOTB Authorize.net files in Magneto and even  tried disabling my entire theme and it doesn't have any impact.

---

Screenshot of code:
http://cl.ly/image/3g1n2x021N2s

---

After looking into this more, it looks like this line in templates/checkout/payments/method.phtml is not returning any HTML:
$this->getPaymentMethodFormHtml($_method)

I found this method and it in-turn is trying to load a child.

```
public function getPaymentMethodFormHtml(Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract $method)
{
     return $this->getChildHtml('payment.method.' . $method->getCode());
}
```

That is about how far I have gotten.

Comment: Code of what specific file are you looking for?

Comment: John, any idea what file you are looking to see? About to rip my hair out over this problem.

Comment: turn logging on and see if you have any errors about missing phtml file

Comment: Nothing appearing in logs. It seems like $this->getPaymentMethodFormHtml($_method) returns an empty string

Comment: Which Magento version are you using and what does your Authorize.net configuration look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try the following steps:

- Check your exception log under `/var/log/exception.log`
- Check your PHP error log
- Disable your current theme by renaming your theme folder eg: `/app/design/frontend/default/themename` >> `/app/design/frontend/default/_themename` - this rules out the possibility of invalid theme/layout XML issues. Make sure it falls back to an untouched base default theme!
- Disable your non-standard extensions by setting `<active>false</active>` in the XMLs found under `/app/etc/modules` one by one.
- Try see if there is a difference in value `$method->getCode()` when saved CC is turned on & off.
- If possible, update the Authorize.net extension. If not, at least check if your `/app/etc/modules/Mage_Authorizenet.xml` is as follows:

> ```
> <config>
>     <modules>
>         <Mage_Authorizenet>
>             <active>true</active>
>             <codePool>core</codePool>
>             <depends>
>                 <Mage_Paygate/>
>                 <Mage_Sales/>
>                 <Mage_Checkout/>
>             </depends>
>         </Mage_Authorizenet>
>     </modules>
> </config>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround if you don't find any solution for your problem.

You can create your own payment form for authorize.net

Authorize.net form used `cc.phtml` file for display Authorize.net fields so you can copy this file and set this form from xml.

Go to your checkout.xmland in `<checkout_onepage_index translate="label">` tag find `checkout.payment.methods` which display all methods put action methods something like this

```
 <action method="setMethodFormTemplate"><method>authorizenet</method><template>payment/form/authorizenet.phtml(which is copy of your cc.phtml)</template></action>
```

I have not test it.

Authorize.net use this block for display form fields so further you can look into this file 
app\code\core\Mage\Paygate\Block\Authorizenet\Form\Cc.php

Comment: I tried this, and still nothing shows up. Also checked logs afterwards and they are clean. There wasn't a record for authorizenet in setMethodFormTemplate xml - should there have been? I only have an XML node for purchaseorder in here.

Comment: Yes put this node after purchaseorder node this is just workarounf if its not working

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I did add it. But before I did there wasn't a record for authnet. Code didn't work.

Comment: Also, looks like the getPaymentMethodFormHtml method is trying to $this->getChildHtml('payment.method.' . $method->getCode()) but <actions are not named....

Comment: action is `payment.method.authorizenet` but i am unable to find this action

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if `Mage_Authorizenet` or `Mage_Paygate` module are disabled in your Magento admin.

> System -> ADVANCED -> Advanced

Make sure that they are enabled there.